# What is the best solution to store password in rails yml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hard code the username and password in the database.yml file in my rails project. But I am afraid that if I upload it into github,my password may be leaked.

So what is the general solution to safely store the password in rails file?

This piece of code is how I stored the password.

Thanks.

```
development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password: 123456789
```

Comment: If you like any answer please accept it so that developers from the future can find it helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Rails > 5.2 then you can use rails Credentials. If it doesn't exist, a key will be created when you run `rails credentials:edit`.

You can edit it like below -

```
EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit
```

and add like below -

```
postgres:
  username:
    development: ABC
    staging: XYZ
  password:
    development: Yzx234354
    staging: "fooBar%@3"
```

The in your `database.yml` you can use it like -

```
development:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:postgres, :username, :development)
  password: Rails.application.credentials.dig(:postgres, :password, :development)
```

Just put the `master.key in .gitignore` and you will be safe from all confusions.

Answer (score 1):

Another option next to using the rails credentials (as answered by Rafayet Monon) would be using an `.env` file that you put into the root of your rails project (and don't check into git). Inside your app, you just use `ENV['MY_VAR']` (or `ENV.fetch('MY_VAR', 'default value if not defined')`).

This can be easily done through the `dotenv-rails` gem that is based on https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv.

I'm using this approach because I also have to handle a variety of other projects (e.g. php based ones) and every project uses the same `.env` approach to keep it consistent for the project teams. As an additional help, a `_.env.example` is committed that contains all the possibilities with a short documentation, so everyone that has to set up the project knows what has to be configured in order to get it up and running.

Also, a nice feature of the ruby dotenv implementation is to check the presence of required variables, which can be put into an initializer. The dotenv README has a section about this.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here looking for an answer and using rails > 6
start by:

```
rails credentials:edit --environment production // or development or test
```

add:

```
mysql:
  username: root
  password: password
```

then in database.yml:

```
username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mysql, :username) %>
password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mysql, :password) %>
```

restart rails and you're good to go
Note: that must be generated for all the environments

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a database username and password. You can just remove those lines. In development environment (localhost) the database is just on your computer so no one else can access it. In production, if you use heroku, they will take care of adding a username and password.

Comment: this might be true for sqlite but if you use postgres as your local DB, you most probably will need to configure it